# Equivalent of LabVIEW Threshold 1D Array Function in Python

Tags: python, arrays, labview

is there an equivalent of labview Threshold 1D Array Function:
http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/glang/threshold_1d_array/
in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of one as is, but it's a very small to write. You can wrap the following into a function

```
p = next(ii for ii,v in enumerate(x) if (v>=y))
frac=p-1.0+(float(y) - x[p-1])/(x[p]-x[p-1])
```

in the above, `x` is the input dataset, `y` is the value for which you want the fractional index. `frac` is, well...

Small explanation: enumerate(x) makes an iterator that returns (index,value) from `x`.  So, they're what get put into `ii,v`.